# Using requirejs instance outside of definition?

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, video.js

I am using **requirejs** to determine dependencies.
I have some code that determines the use of the **Video.js**:

```
require.config({
  'paths': {
    'bc': 'https://players.brightcove.net/1507807800001/default_default/index.min'
  },
  waitSeconds: 30
});
require(['bc'], function() {
  var myPlayer = videojs.getPlayers().myPlayerID;
  myPlayer.on('loadstart', function(){
    myPlayer.play();
  })
});
```

Also I have some code that wants to get an instance and use that **Video.js**:

```
if (typeof myPlayer != "undefined") {
  console.log("myPlayer existence true");
  myPlayer.stop();
} else {
  console.log("myPlayer existence false");
}
```

Is there a way to access outside of the **Video.js**'s definition?
This is a working example https://playcode.io/868784/

Comment: That code must go inside the require bc callback function.

Comment: I understand it. But I'm wondering if there is another solution? Thanks.

Comment: You could use promises, but whatever you use it must wait until the module is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your module and later use it:

```js
require.config({
  'paths': {
    'bc': 'https://players.brightcove.net/1507807800001/default_default/index.min'
  },
  waitSeconds: 30
});
define('myPlayer', ['bc'], function() {
  var myPlayer = videojs.getPlayers().myPlayerID;
  myPlayer.on('loadstart', function(){
    myPlayer.play();
  })

  return myPlayer;
});
```

Video.js:

```js
require(['myPlayer'], function (myPlayer) {
  myPlayer.stop();
});
```

Comment: As result console.log: myPlayer existence false

Comment: My apologies @SergeyKozlov the code was missing a return! Fixed now

Comment: You're right! That's right. Everything works. Thanks.